# Footer on bottom while printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to print content on my html page

the format is

```
<div class="header">Title of the page</div>

<div class="main">Content of the page</div>

<div class="footer">Footer of the page</div>

<div class="page-break"></div>

<div class="header">Title of the page</div>

<div class="main">Content of the page</div>

<div class="footer">Footer of the page</div>

<div class="page-break"></div>

<div class="header">Title of the page</div>

<div class="main">Content of the page</div>

<div class="footer">Footer of the page</div>

<div class="page-break"></div>
```

so there are three pages, pages are added dynamically and this css helps me to break the page while printing

```
.page.break{
    page-break-after:always
}
```

The problem is that the footer comes after the main div, I want it to be at the bottom of page always.

Any help?

Comment: so you only want a single footer?

Comment: No, i want footer in every page. but on the bottom of every page, not where the content ends

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS in to your footer div, it should solve your problem

```
style="clear: both;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could your solution be something similar as in this thread?

[Footer Not Aligning At Bottom Of Content In Print Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944418/footer-not-aligning-at-bottom-of-content-in-print-preview)